# Is there anyway to close client request in golang/gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

Using [gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) framework.

Is there anyway to notify client to close request connection, then server handler can do any back-ground jobs without letting the clients to wait on the connection?

```
func Test(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(200, "ok")
        // close client request, then do some jobs, for example sync data with remote server.
        //
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. By simply returning from the handler. And the background job you want to do, you should put that on a new goroutine.

Note that the connection and/or request may be put back into a pool, but that is irrelevant, the client will see that serving the request ended. You achieve what you want.

Something like this:

```
func Test(c *gin.Context) {
    c.String(200, "ok")
    // By returning from this function, response will be sent to the client
    // and the connection to the client will be closed

    // Started goroutine will live on, of course:
    go func() {
       // This function will continue to execute... 
    }()
}
```

Also see: [Goroutine execution inside an http handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116870/goroutine-execution-inside-an-http-handler)

Comment: You saved me and my life, I was doing this wrong way using message brokers like rabbitMQ