# How to stop perform request created with HTTPClient

Tags: multithreading, http, go

How to stop perform request for example with audio or video stream by some condition like callback or similar like it doing in cURL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807590/how-to-stop-a-goroutine. Also read this article: https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

Comment: Also possible duplicate / related: 1. [cancel a blocking operation in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240133/cancel-a-blocking-operation-in-go); 2. [Goroutine execution inside an http handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116870/goroutine-execution-inside-an-http-handler); 3. [Is there anyway to close client request in golang/gin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470792/is-there-anyway-to-close-client-request-in-golang-gin)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the [context package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context). There is a good blog article on golang.org explaining how to use it [here](https://blog.golang.org/context).

The gist of it is, you create a context object, and pass it to your goroutine that is performing streaming. In your caller goroutine you can cancel the context or set a timeout. In the streaming goroutine you have to check for `context.Done()` and act accordingly.

If the action is actually an http request that you want to cancel, you can do it at the [transport level](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.CancelRequest) (when you get a message on `context.Done()`)