# Break out of 3rd party goroutine that has an infinite loop

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm using this to receive SNMP traps: https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp
Now, lets say I want to programmatically break out of the (taken from [here](https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp/blob/master/examples/trapserver.go)):

> err := tl.Listen("0.0.0.0:9162")

What are my best approaches to this?

I'm somewhat new to Golang and didnt find a way to break out of a goroutine that I have no way of modifying ("3rd party").

Thanks,

Comment: From a quick examination, it does not appear that you can. `TrapListener` should have exposed a `Close()` or `Shutdown()` method that closed the underlying network listener.

Comment: Exactly! I thought though, that there is some way to do that. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cancel a blocking operation in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240133/cancel-a-blocking-operation-in-go/28240299#28240299); and [Goroutine execution inside an http handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116870/goroutine-execution-inside-an-http-handler/31116947#31116947).

Comment: this may help: https://rakyll.org/leakingctx/ https://blog.golang.org/context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: You can't.  There's no way to kill a goroutine (short of killing the entire program) from outside the goroutine.

Long answer: A goroutine can listen for some sort of "terminate" signal (via channels, signals, or any other mechanism).  But ultimately, the goroutine must terminate *from within*.

Looking at the library in your example, it appears this functionality is not provided.

Comment: think i will need to add that then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Standard https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn interface provides special methods `SetDeadline` (together with `SetReadDeadline` and `SetWriteDeadline`) to set a hard connection break time for staled connections. As I see in the [source](https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp/blob/master/gosnmp.go#L39) code:

```
type GoSNMP struct {
    // Conn is net connection to use, typically established using GoSNMP.Connect()
    Conn net.Conn
     ...

    // Timeout is the timeout for the SNMP Query
    Timeout time.Duration
    ...
```

`net.Conn` interface is exported - so you may try to get direct access to it to set up a deadline.

```
type TrapListener struct {
    OnNewTrap func(s *SnmpPacket, u *net.UDPAddr)
    Params    *GoSNMP
    ...
}
```

In its turn `TrapListener` exports `GoSNMP` struct so you may have access to it. Try this:

```
tl := TrapListener{...}
tl.Params.Conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(1*time.Second))
tl.Listen(...)
```

However [this line](https://github.com/soniah/gosnmp/blob/master/trap.go#L113) disensures me - looks like it doesn't use stored connection and its options:

```
func (t *TrapListener) Listen(addr string) (err error) {
    ...
    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", udpAddr)
    ....
}
```

But you may try :)